# How to inherit from HASH_TABLE in Eiffel?

Tags: inheritance, eiffel

I want to make a derived class of HASH_TABLE which implements a few additional features. I tried implementing it like this:

```
class HASH_TABLE2[G->HASHABLE]
inherit
    HASH_TABLE[G,G]
        rename
            make as make_2
        end
create
    make
feature
    make (capacity_ : INTEGER)
        do
            make_2(capacity_)
        end
end
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Creation instruction uses call to improper feature.

Feature name: make_2 (n: INTEGER_32)
Line: 1156
      do
->      create Result.make (n)
        if object_comparison then
```

I don't understand why. If I do the same with inherit ARRAY[G], then it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the feature `empty_duplicate` (mentioned in the error message) creates a new instance of a hash table using the original creation procedure `make`. However, this feature is no longer a creation procedure in `HASH_TABLE2`. The solution is to redefine `empty_duplicate` accordingly:

```
class HASH_TABLE2 [G -> HASHABLE]

inherit
    HASH_TABLE [G, G]
        rename
            make as make_2
        redefine
            empty_duplicate
        end

create
    make

feature
    
    make (capacity_: INTEGER)
        do
            make_2 (capacity_)
        end

feature {NONE} -- Duplication

    empty_duplicate (n: INTEGER_32): like Current
            -- <Precursor>
        do
            create Result.make (n)
            if object_comparison then
                Result.compare_objects
            end
        end

end
```

Note that although the body of `empty_duplicate` redeclaration looks identical to the original one, it calls `make` from `HASH_TABLE2` that has nothing to do with `make` from `HASH_TABLE` because the latter was renamed into `make_2`.

This brings us to the question whether `make` from `HASH_TABLE` could remain the creation procedure in `HASH_TABLE2`. Unless the given example is a simplification, this is feasible and compiles without an issue:

```
class HASH_TABLE2 [G -> HASHABLE]
inherit
    HASH_TABLE [G, G]
create
    make
end
```

Comment: Wouldn' it be more elegant to `redefine` without `rename` using `Precursor`?

Comment: @U.Windl It would, however, the original question explicitly states that the creation procedure was renamed, and another procedure was used as a creation one (e.g., it might be needed if the creation procedure had some other arguments, not shown in the MWE).